# Create a package files python

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I need to create a script to copy all files .class and .xml from multiple folders and generate a package something like tar type, those diferent  path folders will be filled when the script runs, is this possible?

I'm using linux - Centos

Thanks

Comment: Which version of Python 3.x are you using? If you're stuck on 3.1, the more powerful features of `tarfile` are a bit different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Python's standard library comes with [multiple archiving modules](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/archiving.html), and more are available from PyPI and elsewhere.

I'm not sure how you want to fill in the paths to the things to include, but let's say you've already got that part done, and you have a list or iterator full of (appropriately relative) pathnames to files. Then, you can just do this:

```
with tarfile.TarFile('package.tgz', 'w:gz') as tar:
    for pathname in pathnames:
        tar.add(pathname)
```

---

But you don't even have to gather all the files one by one, because `tarfile` can do that for you. Let's say your script just takes one or more directory names as command-line arguments, and you want it to recursively add all of the files whose names end in `.xml` or `.class` anywhere in any of those directories:

```
def package_filter(info):
    if info.isdir() or os.path.splitext(info.name)[-1] in ('.xml', '.class'):
        return info
    else:
        return None

with tarfile.TarFile('package.tgz', 'w:gz', filter=package_filter) as tar:
    for pathname in sys.argv[1:]:
        tar.add(pathname)
```

---

See the [examples](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/tarfile.html#examples) for more. But mainly, read the docs for `TarFile`'s constructor and `open` method.